# SSMS query window hyperlink in text

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012, database-mail

I've put together a variable of type nvarchar(max) for the body of an email being send with db_sendmail.  The problem is that in copying the body over from a stock email message into the SSMS query window, only those hyperlinks that are actual web addresses come over properly hyperlinked.  Others do not.  Is there anything I can do, short of sending the message in HTML format instead of text?

Comment: If you're inserting text using a SQL query window in SSMS, you are most likely just inserting that text. The SSMS screen may try to be helpful and allow you to ctrl+click on things that it thinks look like valid URLs, but it will not actually send HTML tags to the DB that aren't in your literal string.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you are sending a plain text email using xxxx but when it is received only valid web addresses are formatted?

Can you see that the problem is not the sending it is because you are using plain text. The apparent formatting is coming from the client that receives the email.

If you want formatted email you will need to send as html.